# How to validate that atleast one question is answered on a survey list where none of the questions are required?

Tags: survey-list, validation

I have a survey list that has 2 questions, the first being a rating with a subset of 4 criteria to rate on and the second is just a questions and comments textbox.

None of these are required, however I would like to ensure that blank forms are not submitted, so atleast one part needs to be filled, can this be done via the browser or would this require custom code?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Any help will be appreciated and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second question being a multiline textbox you unfortunately rules out list validations.

The only options left are:

- Use code and add an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx) this will allow you to present an error message to the user
- Create a SharePoint designer workflow which is set to start when an item is created or modified and if both fields are empty delete the item